# git push виснет после Total

Tags: git

Склонировал с сервера проект.
Внес изменения и пытаюсь сделать push -

```
git push origin dkostin
```

Пишет

```
 Counting objects: 56, done.
 Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
 Compressing objects: 100% (32/32), done.
 Writing objects: 100% (35/35), 4.82 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
 Total 35 (delta 24), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

и висит.

Что может быть не так?

Comment: вы терминалом делаете `git push` ? или пользуетесь `IDE`?
и еще одно после того как виснет команда отмените его, и посмотрите он скинул все на сервер или нет?

Comment: а может фаервол какой-то?

Comment: @Razmik Galstyan в терминале, не скинул

Comment: @thecoder не понял?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan это ответ на ваши вопросы же: пуш в терминале, на сервер всё не скинул.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin различия есть между вопросами

Comment: @Nick Volynkin явно не из-за больших файлов, висит уже 1,5 часа
может что-то с правами?

Comment: @thecoder прочитал внимательно лог. И правда, пять килобайт. Ладно, поищу ещё варианты. Если вы найдете, то опубликуйте, пожалуйста.

Comment: К слову, соединение ssh или http?

Comment: Кто найдет ответ - с меня 50 репы конкурсом. ;)

Comment: если бы автор вопроса ответил - есть ли у него фаерволы или что то подобное. У меня такое было - я был в Турции в октябре 2016 и там в этот момент забанили github. Эффекты были почти такие же.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin - ssh

Comment: @KoVadim фаерволов нет

Answer (score 2):

Вообщем проблема оказалась в правах.
Репо на сервере был создан под рутом, соответственно прав у юзера писать туда что-то нет.

Comment: Ха, круто. Я даже не подумал о таком варианте, когда вы руками репозиторий создали. )